# httpBackend mocked json file response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I have this post request mocking code into a beforeEach function

```
    $httpBackend.when('POST', CONFIG.get('MAIN_URL_FOR_REST_SERVICES') + 'actions/search').respond(200,
        '[{"name": "all","id": "1"}]'
    );
```

How can I store the httpBackend response into a json file?

```
[{"name": "all","id": "1"}]
```

stored into actions.json

Thanks!

Comment: I'm a bit confused at what you're trying to accomplish. `$httpBackend` is a tool for testing code, so where are you trying to save the response, and how do you want in accomplished? Like a popup to the user, like downloading a file?

Comment: this is just a mock for post http request, thus, when the CONFIG.get('MAIN_URL_FOR_REST_SERVICES') + 'actions/search') url is called response should be '[{"name": "all","id": "1"}]', instead of hardcoding it into js file i want this json into a separate file.

Comment: something like this:    $httpBackend.when('POST', CONFIG.get('MAIN_URL_FOR_REST_SERVICES') + 'actions/search').respond(200, actions.json);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and the answer is:

```
    jasmine.getJSONFixtures().fixturesPath = 'base/test/unit/authz/api_mock/';
    $httpBackend.when('POST', CONFIG.get('MAIN_URL_FOR_REST_SERVICES') + 'actions/search').respond(function() {
        return [200, window.getJSONFixture('actions.json')];
    });
```